# How do you set a strftime with javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, time, strftime

I need to custom format dates. In ruby, I would use strftime, or string formatted time, to accomplish this.

```
now = Time.new
now.strftime '%a, %d of %b' #=> "Sat, 27 of Jun"
```

Does javascript use strftime or some equivalent? How can I get a similar effect in javascript?

Comment: MomentJs introduced new formatting tokens in version 2.0 and supports many language formating [documented here](https://gist.github.com/timrwood/e72f2eef320ed9e37c51)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**UPDATE**

> Arguments of toLocaleString method can also configure the format of the
> dates. This is supported in modern browser versions, you can see more
> information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility).

```js
let date = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 5, 27, 12, 0, 0))
, options = {weekday: 'short', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(date.toLocaleString('es-ES', options)); //sáb. 27 de jun.
```

In JavaScript there are methods to create dates, but no native code to format. You can read about **[Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)**. But there are [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) that do. Particularly for me the best library to use it deeply is [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/). So you can do something like as: `moment().format('dd, d of MMMM')`

However, if you do not want to use a library you have access to the following native Date properties:

```js
var now = new Date();

document.write(now.toUTCString() + "<br>")
document.write(now.toTimeString() + "<br>")
```

Here are some [Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) properties:

```
toDateString()        // Converts the date portion of a Date object into a readable string
toGMTString()         // Deprecated. Use the toUTCString() method instead
toISOString()         // Returns the date as a string, using the ISO standard
toJSON()              // Returns the date as a string, formatted as a JSON date
toLocaleDateString()  // Returns the date portion of a Date object as a string, using locale conventions
toLocaleTimeString()  // Returns the time portion of a Date object as a string, using locale conventions
toLocaleString()      // Converts a Date object to a string, using locale conventions
toString()            // Converts a Date object to a string
toTimeString()        // Converts the time portion of a Date object to a string
toUTCString()         // Converts a Date object to a string, according to universal time
```

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of good strftime() ports for javascript.

https://github.com/samsonjs/strftime is very comprehensive and a lot of specifiers from C-lang and Ruby have been ported.

https://thdoan.github.io/strftime/ is simpler if you're looking for something lite.

I appreciate Walter's very detailed and clear answer about custom implementation, but I personally wouldn't want to write code on my own for common things like date formatting(I actually came back to using libs above after seeing repeated issues with custom code).